# Как добавить клавиши CapsLk Backspace Enter Shift Tab Ctrl пробел к виртуальной клавиатуре

Tags: javascript

```js
const keyboard = [96, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 45, 61, 113, 119, 101, 114, 116, 121, 117, 105, 111, 112, 91, 93, 92, 97, 115, 100, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 59, 39, 13, 122, 120, 99, 118, 98, 110, 109, 44, 46, 47];

//document.onkeypress = function(event){
   // console.log(event);
  //  keyboard.push(event.charCode);
 //   console.log(keyboard);
//}
function init(){
    let out = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < keyboard.length; i++){
        if(i == 13 || i == 26 || i == 38){
            out +='<div class="clearfix"></div>';
        }
        out +='<div class="k-key" data="' + keyboard[i] + '" >'+String.fromCharCode(keyboard[i])+'</div>';
    }
    document.querySelector('#keyboard').innerHTML = out;
}
init();

document.onkeypress = function (event) {
    console.log(event.code);
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    document.querySelectorAll('#keyboard .k-key').forEach(function(element){
        element.classList.remove('active');
    });
    document.querySelector('#keyboard .k-key[data="' +event.keyCode + '"]').classList.add('active');
}
document.querySelectorAll('#keyboard .k-key').forEach(function (element) {
element.onclick = function(event){
    document.querySelectorAll('#keyboard .k-key').forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.remove('active');
    });
    let code  = this.getAttribute('data');
    this.classList.add('active');
    console.log(code);
}
});
```

```css
#keyboard {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
}

#keyboard::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.k-key {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    float: left;
}

.clearfix {
    
    clear: both;
}

.active {
    background: #0366d6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Keyboard</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="keyboard.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="keyboard"></div>
        <script src="keyboard.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: О_о а для какой цели выбраны именно коды символов, а не просто `['a', 'b', 'c'...]` ? Можно было делать два массива: Один с капсом, другой - без. При клике на капс - всё также переключать ему активный класс. В зависимости от которого при клике доставать заглавный или маленький символ.